# Want to add XSD documentation to Javadoc generated pojo JIBX

Tags: documentation, xsd, jibx

Any ideas on how to include the xsd:annotation and xsd:documentation content defined in the schema as javadoc in the generated pojo using jibx???

For now I only get the schema fragment on top of the class but cant see the annotation documentation for the schema.

thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be experiencing an unexpected behavior, unless the lack of details in your question threw this answer off... If you're still in a bind after attempting troubleshooting as described below, the best would be for you to update your request with more information, such as an XSD fragment showing the setup, the versions you're using (Java, JiBX) and the command line you use for your codegen utility.

Start by taking a look at [customizations](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-customs.html) documentation; make sure that the ***import-docs*** option, which is responsible to *"Convert xs:documentation annotations in the schema definition to Javadocs in the generated [...]"*, is not set to false. The default value is true, so it should work...

Check that from a command line perspective, you're not overriding it. Alternatively, you could ensure is set explicitly (see [this](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/fromschema/codegen-customs.html#command)).

Answer (score 0):

JiBX *does* automatically includes xsd:documentation content in the generated source code which will end up in your javadocs.
For a nice example, take a look at the opentravel.org schema which is included in the JiBX schema library.
Here is the opentravel schema definition for a 'ping' message:
http://opentravel.org/2011B/OTA_PingRQ.xsd.
Now download and unzip the javadoc.jar for the generated code from maven central:
[http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.jibx.schema.org.opentravel._2011B.ping.PingRQ](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3aorg.jibx.schema.org.opentravel._2011B.ping.PingRQ)
Notice how the xsd:documentation displays nicely in the javadoc.
Hope this example helps!
Don Corley
JiBX contributor